Category equivalences realizable as isomorphisms in some category?
Is there a category in which isomorphisms are precisely the equivalences of categories?
This was motivated by the observation that we have functor categories wherein the isomorphisms are precisely the natural isomorphisms.

"isomorphism" is a weird word, and it can mean different things in different contexts (or even in the same context to different people). In the 2-category of categories, the bi-invertible maps are the equivalences of categories. But you need to live in a (2/bi)-category, since the notion of equivalence of categories is inherently 2-dimensional.

I guees I will come back when I have studied (2/bi)-categories.

I wouldn't worry about studying bicategories before learning about equivalences of categories. Bicategories are considerably more complicated than categories, and the literature is not super easy to peak into. All you have to worry about is a very special case, the 2-category of categories. Riehl has a chapter on this.

@IsAdisplayName Finally, I read about 2-cats. You said that equivalences are bi-invertible maps in the 2-cat of categories. However, the only place that I can find something on bi-invertible maps seems to be this nLab entry, which is definitely not beginner-friendly. Can you explain instead?

yes, the nlab has a way of doing such things. A bi-invertible map is a map with both a left inverse (also called a retraction) and a right inverse (also called a section). By (left/right) inverse, we mean, invertible up to natural isomorphism. That nlab page is saying the same thing, but it is formulating it in the setting of an (even) higher category, and so it has to replace "up to natural isomorphism" with some higher categorical analogue.
This notion of bi-invertible map is logically equivalent to the standard definition of equivalence. I only used it out of force of habit.

The comments contain what's probably the pedagogically correct answer: no, equivalences are really a 2-categorical notion and can't be fully reduced to isomorphisms. But you can get pretty close, by considering the 1-category whose objects are categories and whose morphisms are natural isomorphism classes of functors. In this category, which I should note is generally quite chaotic and ill-behaved, the isomorphisms are precisely the isomorphism classes of equivalences, and that's the closest you're going to get to what you asked for.
